# How do I access the .Name of a regex Group?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2017

I have a regex that is like this:

```
var a = new Regex("(?<PageNumber>.{2})(?<ListType>.{2})", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Match:

```
a.Match("02KLThisIsATest");
```

When I then after a successfull match use:

```
foreach (Group gr in match.Groups)
{
...
}
```

I can see clearly in the debugger that the "Name" is filled out and thus "0", "Page'Number", "ListType". BUT I cannot in the source use: gr.Name.
The compiler just says "no there is no Name".

Now my question is: How can I access the Name?

Comment: As far as I remember you have to use `match.Groups["PageNumber"]` for example

Comment: can you post a sample string which is used

Comment: @Asunez my problem is that I need the name to dynamically fill a dictionary. Thus I need to somehow access it...and the debuger clearly sees the attribute. (else i will have to go via groupnames....but that is cumbersome......)

Comment: @Shantanu edited the sample string in....although I don't think there is much of a difference there as its an attribute of the Group that the debugger can access and clearly see but not the program code.

Comment: You get groups by `match.Groups["group_name"].Value`

Comment: Which version of the framework are you targeting? The `Group.Name` property does exist, but not in older versions of the desktop framework. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.name?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Group_Name

Comment: @JonSkeet 4.6.1.   As far as I understand now it shouldnt work thus. Although the debugger (variable watch) knows it and can use it oO .

Comment: @Thomas: Even though you're *targeting* 4.6.1, I suspect you'll find you're *executing* against 4.7.something due to the in-place nature of .NET desktop framework updates.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  var a = new Regex("(?<PageNumber>.{2})(?<ListType>.{2})", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

  GroupCollection groups = a.Match("02KLThisIsATest").Groups;
  var names = a.GetGroupNames();

foreach (var grpName in names )
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Group: {0}, Value: {1}", grpName, groups[grpName].Value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected when I am running on .Net runtime > 4.6.2. Some properties are not accessible because of boxing\ unboxing of an object to an underlying abstract or base type so that extra members in inherited or child class are hidden. I made it to `dynamic` to expose all public\ protected members.

Related: [Why some properties/fields are being visible in debugger, but not accessible from the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373841/why-some-properties-fields-are-being-visible-in-debugger-but-not-accessible-fro)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new Regex("(?<PageNumber>.{2})(?<ListType>.{2})", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    var match = a.Match("02KLThisIsATest");

    foreach (dynamic gr in match.Groups)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        Console.WriteLine(gr.Name + " | " + gr.Value);
    }
}
```

Published the example in, https://rextester.com/FKYG47557

Comment: Interesting - I wouldn't expect it to work when targeting .NET 4.5, and it doesn't on my box. As far as I can see, it was introduced in .NET 4.7. (How are you compiling it locally? What does your project file specify as the target?)

Comment: Oh, yes it is .Net 4.7.2. But in the RexTester.com, it showed as .Net 4.5.

Comment: Right, I think that's just rextester.com being imprecise. I suggest you edit your post to indicate that it was .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: Hm can it be that the devuger uses 4.7.2 even if i use a slughlty lesser version?

Comment: @JonSkeet, now, I figured to make it work in older versions too. This answered me that puzzle why some properties are visible in debugger but not in compiler.