# Runtime type of CheckBox RoutedEventArgs.UserInitiated

Tags: wpf, .net-6.0, routedeventargs

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55373962/4682228) answer, how does one find the runtime type of a property that is visible in the debugger? I'd like to access `UserInitiated`.

(I now also secondarily want to know what this property means, since even when clicking manually, `UserInitiated` returns `false`. There doesn't seem to be meaningful documentation online.)

[image: debugger for RoutedEventArgs]

This from-scratch scenario is a WPF .NET 6 project with a Check Box control and a `CheckBox_Checked` event handler.

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { }
```

The original type of `RoutedEventArgs e` is unclear. Additional properties, such as `e.UserInitiated` available in the debugger won't compile.

Even in the Locals window, the type is still marked `System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs`, which is ostensibly correct. But [RoutedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) doesn't contain the property `UserInitiated`. Even trying different types, looking for questions and documentation online, using `GetType()`, and typecasting to related types hasn't yielded a useful answer.

The purpose is to differentiate between when code updates a check box vs. a user manually clicking on the check box.

Comment: Checkbox inherits from button base. Use clicked for user initiated. Better still, don't use events at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to the basic problem, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33319175/4682228), it's possible to make the difference between a user checking a box and the code by using the check box's `Click` event.

This doesn't so much answer the `UserInitiated` question as practically solve the problem at hand.